# Square root of an inverse gamma distributed random variable

Tags: probability, distributions, gamma-distribution

I work on the grouped t copula and try to replicate part of the following paper:
"The t copula with Multiple Parameters of Degrees of Freedom: Bivariate Characteristics and Application to Risk Management", Luo & Shevchenko (2010).

My Question:

I need the distribution of the following random variable:
$$
Y = \sqrt{\frac\nu X}
$$
where X is Chi square distributed with v degrees of freedom.

I found out that the following random variabe Z is inverse gamma distributed with alpha = v/2 and beta = v/2,
$$
Z = {\frac\nu X}
$$

So, basically I am looking for the distribution of the square root of an inverse gamma distributed random variable.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Isn't this just the generalized gamma? (Generalized gammas are gammas to a power; the chi-square is gamma to a power.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have derived the answer using Mathematica:

```
PDF[TransformedDistribution[Sqrt[x], x \[Distributed] InverseGammaDistribution[\[Nu]/2, \[Nu]/2]], x]
```

results in a pdf for your transformed variable of the form:

$\frac{2^{1-\frac{\nu}{2}} e^{-\frac{\nu}{2x^2}}x^{-1-\nu}\nu^{\nu/2}}{Gamma(\nu/2)}$

I am not sure if this represents a particular named distribution, but hope that knowing the pdf may help in some way.

Update: the inverse cdf for this distribution is:

$\frac{\nu}{2 InverseGammaRegularised(\nu/2,x)}$

Best,

Ben

Comment: If $Z$ is $IG$, we are looking for the distribution of 

$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{X}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{X}}, $$
where $X$ follows a Gamma-distribution, right? Apparently, the distribution of $\sqrt{X}$ is known as the [Nagakami distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakagami_distribution). So, a possible name would be "inverse Nagakami distribution".

Comment: What I need is the quantile function / inverse cdf of this distribution, since I want to use it in R. @ Ben: Is it possible to derive this with Mathematica? @ Chrisoph: Doesn't $$\sqrt X$$ in your example follow a generalized gamma distribution? The Nagakami distribution is already implemented in R but I am not sure how I could use this for my problem...

Comment: Ok, I have updated my answer to include this result (I'm not asking for an up vote, but as Christoph says, it is typically the way to thank people).

Comment: I would really like to give you an up vote but I can't since I need 15 reputation :( !?

Comment: I am not sure about the generalized one. Why do you think so? I am also not sure if you can use my result. You could try to apply the [change of variables rule](http://www.randomservices.org/random/dist/Transformations.html) for r.v.s to check @ben18785 's finding by trying to derive the distribution of $1/W$ if $W$ follows a Nagakami distribution.

Comment: I derived the generalized one the following way: $$ X \tilde{} \chi^2(v)$$
--> 
$$cX =  \Gamma(k=v/2, \theta=2c) $$
-->
$$ Y = (1/v)*X =\Gamma(k=v/2, \theta=2/v) $$
-->
$$ 1/Y =Ig(v/2, v/2) $$

where Ig is the inverse gamma distribution and $$ \sqrt{Y} = generalized gamma (p=2, d = v, a=\sqrt{v/2}) $$