# What kind of distribution does this have?

Tags: self-study, gamma-distribution, inverse-gamma-distribution, distribution-identification, nakagami-distribution

Currently I'm trying to figure out the distribution of the following:

$X \sim \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{Gamma(n,\beta)}}$ where the denominator follows a $Gamma(n,\beta)$ distribution.

I've checked out these links:

1. [Square root of an inverse gamma distributed random variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/143350/square-root-of-an-inverse-gamma-distributed-random-variable?noredirect=1&lq=1);
2. [Square root of inverse gamma distribution?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5119/square-root-of-inverse-gamma-distribution?noredirect=1&lq=1);
3. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-gamma_distribution;
4. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakagami_distribution.

I'm just not sure how to connect the dots. I think I'm playing with some kind of Nakagami distribution? Just trying to figure out a clean way of expressing $X$ and knowing what it's parameters would look like. I need to find it's mean and variance if I can.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $Z$ have a Gamma$(n,1)$ distribution, which has density

$$f_Z(z) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(n)}\, z^{n-1} \,e^{-z}\,\mathrm{d}z.$$

Let $\lambda \gt 0.$  Then

$$X = \sqrt{\lambda}Z^{-1/2}$$

ranges from $0$ to $\infty$ and

$$Z = \frac{\lambda}{X^2}.$$

Substituting $z = \lambda x^{-2}$ and (therefore) $|\mathrm{d}z| = 2\lambda x^{-3}\mathrm{d}x$ we find

$$f_X(x)\mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{\Gamma(n)} (\lambda x^{-2})^{n-1}\,e^{-\lambda/x^2}\,2\lambda x^{-3}\mathrm{d} x = \frac{2\lambda^{n}}{\Gamma(n)}\, x^{-2n-1}\,e^{-\lambda/x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x.$$

Set $\lambda = \sqrt{n/\beta}$ or $\lambda=\sqrt{n\beta}$ depending on whether $\beta$ is a scale or rate parameter, respectively.

This is a [Generalized Inverse Gamma distribution](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseGammaDistribution.html).

---

**To find the moments of $X$ it's simpler to ignore all this.**  Let $k$ be the moment ($k=1$ for the expectation, etc.) and observe

$$E(X^k) = E\left(\lambda^{k/2} Z^{-k/2}\right) = \lambda^{k/2} \frac{1}{\Gamma(n)}\int_0^\infty z^{-k/2}\,z^{n-1}\,e^{-z}\,\mathrm{d}z = \lambda^{k/2}\frac{\Gamma(n-k/2)}{\Gamma(n)}.$$

[image: Figure]

Here is a histogram for $10^5$ realizations of $Z$ with $n=8,$ $\beta=1/3$ (the rate).  On it I have superimposed the theoretical distribution, which is in close agreement.  The following `R` code reports the mean and variance of this sample and the theoretical values; they, too, agree closely.

```R
n <- 8
beta <- 1/3
n.sim <- 1e5

Z <- rgamma(n.sim, n, beta)
X <- sqrt(n)/sqrt(Z)

hist(X, freq=FALSE, breaks=50, col="#f8f8f8")
curve(dgamma(n/x^2, n, beta) * 2*n/x^3, xname="x", add=TRUE, col="Red", lwd=2)

c(Mean=mean(X), Formula=sqrt(n*beta) * exp(lgamma(n-1/2) - lgamma(n)))
c(mu2=mean(X^2), Formula=n*beta / (n-1))
c(Variance=var(X), Formula=n*beta*(1/(n-1) - exp(2*(lgamma(n-1/2) - lgamma(n)))))
```

Comment: (+1) I wrote a paper in 1991 on the [generalised inverse Normal distribution](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/016771529190174P) that has essentially the same form, except that it is defined on $\mathbb R$, hence with different odd moments.

Answer (score 10):

The $\sqrt{n}$ term in the numerator only scales your random variable, so we can disregard it for now.

The square root of a gamma distributed variable is [Nakagami distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakagami_distribution). We are looking for the reciprocal of that, which could be called an "inverse Nakagami distribution".

[Louzada et al. (2018)](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8374971) looks like it might be helpful. It defines exactly the kind of inverse Nakagami you are looking for and gives a number of propositions, such as the moments. You would just need to scale them appropriately by your $\sqrt{n}$ scaling factor.