# Is this an Inverse Gamma?

Tags: bayesian, optimization, inverse-gamma-distribution

My professor wrote in an assignment that a random variable with an Inverse-Gamma 1 distribution has density function
$$f_{ig}(\sigma|d,s) = C_g^{-1}(d,s)\cdot \sigma^{-(d+1)}\cdot \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\frac{s}{\sigma^2}\right)$$
where
$$C_g(d,s) = \frac{1}{2}\cdot \Gamma\left(\frac{d}{2}\right)\cdot \left(\frac{2}{s}\right)^{\frac{d}{2}}.$$
This is quite different from the standard IG1 density. It does not appear to be a reparameterization or a form of the [Generalized IG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse_Gaussian_distribution). If you plot it against a "normal" IG PDF with the same moments (mean = 0.5, SD = 2) the curves are quite different.

I find the $\sigma^2$ in the exponent to be particularly odd.

However, I'm not ready to say that this is a (massive) typo just yet. One reason is that - using this density as a prior - I get a posterior mode that is far less dependent on an initial guess than using the regular IG1 PDF.

One way to put my question, then, is: is this one of those optimization tricks of the trade or just a typo?

[Also: This is a prior density. So as long as this is proportional to a proper PDF I should be fine. (But I'll need to try to check that eventually.).]

Answer (score 3):

Okay, it seems I wasn't googling well enough. An Inverse-Gamma-1 (emphasis on the "-1") distribution seems to be a creature of Bayesian Macro. See page 5 of the "[Prior Distributions in Dynare](http://file:///home/michael/Dropbox/classes/ECON482/literature/DynareDistributions.pdf)".

I found this in the answer to the question: [Square root of inverse gamma distribution?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5119/square-root-of-inverse-gamma-distribution).